# How to filter cases in a data.table by multiple conditions defined in another data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I wondered whether there is any efficient way to filter a data.table by multiple conditions defined in another data.table. There are 2 data.table in this case:

```
# the filter data.table defines the condition
dt_filter<-data.table(A=c(1,2),B=c(8,7))
# dt1 the data.table to be filtered
dt1<-data.table(A=rep(c(1,2),5),B=c(8,4,3,1,1,5,9,7,1,1),C=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)))

ls_tmp<-lapply (1:nrow(dt_filter),function(i){
# exclude the record with the A&B defined the filter
dt1_add<-dt1[A==dt_filter[[i,1]]&B!=dt_filter[[i,2]]]
})
result<- rbindlist(ls_tmp)
```

It seems my sample is not efficient because of lapply loop. I am not sure how to re-write it by some other way.

Comment: What is group? Please label `A, B, C`. `B!=dt_filter[...` The not equal here, is that a typo?

Comment: @Vlo The column A is the group id.

Comment: Your code is really hard to read. Try cleaning up & simplifying, for our sake and yours!

Comment: @Señor O I'm sorry. They have been edited.

Comment: What is the point of selecting the rows with matching B `dt2_add` and non-matching B `dt1_add` then binding the list together. Isn't that just equal to selecting all the members of a group? This goes back to my original question is the `!=` in `dt1_add` a typo?

Comment: may I suggest the vignette on [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944) as well as the [data.table manual](cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf)?

Comment: @VIo The filter defines the B value to be deleted in each group of dt1. Then use the record with same B value from dt2 to replace the deleted records. In other words, the record in dt1 will be updated by the record in dt2 with the condition defined in the filter(B column is the condition definition in the filter).

Comment: `dt1` and `dt2` have exactly identical columns A and B... Why exactly do you need `dt2` then for your task?

Comment: C column is not same.

Comment: That's irrelevant because you replace column C of `dt2` with values from `dt1`. I still don't understand what's the purpose of `dt2` here...

Comment: Made the question simple. Hope it is clear now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
setkey(dt1, A)

dt1[dt_filter, allow = T][B != i.B, !'i.B']
#   A B C
#1: 1 1 1
#2: 1 1 2
#3: 1 3 1
#4: 1 9 2
#5: 2 1 1
#6: 2 1 2
#7: 2 4 1
#8: 2 5 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Two other solutions which read more clearly and which don't need to `setkey`:

`dt1[ which(dt1$A == dt_filter$A & dt1$B != dt_filter$B) ,]`

Now using `%in%`

`dt1[dt1$A %in% dt_filter$A & !(dt1$B %in% dt_filter$B) ,]`

Comment: Since data.table uses "with" by default, I believe you could simplify further to: 
`dt1[ which(A == dt_filter$A & B != dt_filter$B) , ]`