# Apply filter by group without using join and by using data.table in R

Tags: r, filter, data.table, percentile

The objective of my code is to apply a percentile-based cutoff on a specific column defined by a group.

I found several threads on SO such as:

- [Efficient way to filter one data frame by ranges in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454565/efficient-way-to-filter-one-data-frame-by-ranges-in-another/)
- [Subsetting data frame with multiple date conditions for ranges in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726882/subsetting-data-frame-with-multiple-date-conditions-for-ranges-in-between?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Efficient way to filter one data frame by ranges in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454565/efficient-way-to-filter-one-data-frame-by-ranges-in-another)
- [How to filter cases in a data.table by multiple conditions defined in another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705305/how-to-filter-cases-in-a-data-table-by-multiple-conditions-defined-in-another-da)

Unfortunately, these threads either don't apply filter based on a group or don't use `data.table` or `base-R`

I am specifically looking for a **method without join**. `Base R`-based method would be fine, but I would really love `data.table`-based method because I have huge size of data. I was able to do what I want to do with join, but I am looking for even better method that possibly avoids join.

Here's my input data:

```
Input_File <- structure(list(Zone = c("East", "East", "East", "East", "East", 
"East", "East", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West"), Fiscal.Year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018), Transaction.ID = c(132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 171, 171, 172, 173, 175, 176, 177, 178
), L.Qty = c(3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1), A.Qty = c(0, 
0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0), I.Qty = c(2, 2, 2, 0, 
1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)), .Names = c("Zone", "Fiscal.Year", 
"Transaction.ID", "L.Qty", "A.Qty", "I.Qty"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's my code (using join):

```
  Input_File <- data.table::as.data.table(Input_File)
  Q <- data.table::as.data.table(data.frame(Zone=c("East","West"), Ten_percentile=c(2017,2018)))
  O <- Q[Input_File,on=c("Zone")] [Fiscal.Year>=Ten_percentile]
```

Brief explanation about my code: I am applying `Ten_percentile` cutoff on `Fiscal.Year` grouped by `Zone`.

Here's the cutoff table:

```
 Q
   Zone Ten_percentile
1: East           2017
2: West           2018
```

Here's the expected output:

```
O
   Zone Ten_percentile Fiscal.Year Transaction.ID L.Qty A.Qty I.Qty
1: East           2017        2017            171     1     0     3
2: West           2018        2018            177     2     0     1
3: West           2018        2018            178     1     0     1
```

and here's the output in `dput` format

```
structure(list(Zone = structure(c(1L,2L,2L),
  .Label = c("East","West"), class = "factor"),
  Ten_percentile = c(2017,2018,2018),
  Fiscal.Year = c(2017,2018,2018),
  Transaction.ID = c(171,177,178), L.Qty = c(1,2,1),
  A.Qty = c(0,0,0), I.Qty = c(3,1,1)),
  .Names = c("Zone","Ten_percentile","Fiscal.Year","Transaction.ID", 
  "L.Qty","A.Qty","I.Qty"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Thanks in advance for any help extended to me. I am a big fan of `data.table`. Hence, I want to learn different ways to solve the same problem and become well versed in `data.table` and `base-R`.

Comment: Instead of doing it in two steps, you can do a non-equi join `as.data.table(Input_File)[Q, on = .(Zone, Fiscal.Year >= Ten_percentile)]`

Comment: Please, explain what you consider as *better method* and why you do not want to use join. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe - Thanks for your kind message. I am not an expert, so I wasn't sure whether there is anything better we can do in terms of speed by using filter. Specifically, I know that in `data.table`, we can `do j by group`, but I am unsure whether we can `filter` by `group` directly without `join`. This post was more of a stretch post to learn new ways of solving problem. I loved akrun's non-equi join, but it's a join at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

We can do a non-equi join

```
res <- as.data.table(Input_File)[Q, c(.SD, list(Ten_percentile = Ten_percentile)),
                 on = .(Zone, Fiscal.Year >= Ten_percentile)]
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Please correct me if I am wrong: Isn't this the same as my solution (using join)? I believe I am looking for a solution without join.

Comment: @watchtower Here, I am using a non-equi join instead of two step